# How to allow requests from forwarded domain to DDNS go into sub folders?

Tags: ssl, ddns

So let me try to describe what's going on.

So I have a domain, the domain is set to permanently forward (301) to my DDNS and the DDNS is pointed to my server running IIS and a small application therein.

I am trying to complete an ssl cert and part of that is to prove you own the domain.

The hidden well-known directory has a text file with a code that I assume the provider just wants to match on to prove ownership.

Anyway, if I go to domain.com -- I successfully get routed to the application as I always have.

If go directly from the DDNS -- I also successfully get routed to the application.

When I tried to go to the domain.com/.well-known/someFolder/importantcheckfile.txt -- I get a 404

However if I go to DDNS/.well-known/someFolder/importantcheckfile.txt -- I am successfully able to see the contents of the file.

I am unsure why using the DDNS allows me into sub folders, but the domain being forwarded to the DDNS does not.

Any clues would be most appreciated. Chatgpt was a rather helpful chap, but we started going in circles after about a half hour.

Comment: This depends on how the redirect is exactly done, but these information are not provided.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich do you mean from the domain provider? As in how they are forwarding? If so its Godaddy and it says in the options when configuring the forwarding to select Permanent 301. Let me know if you are asking for something different.

Comment: It sounds like what you have configured at your provider is their http redirect service. What you probably should have configured is a dns CNAME record. The latter allows you to host your own website under your own domain with your content including setting up a https website for your own domain.

Comment: Questions should demonstrate reasonable information technology management practices. Questions that relate to unsupported hardware or software platforms or unmaintained environments may not be suitable for Server Fault.

Comment: @HBruijn, thanks. That gave me the tip I needed. Appreciate the help.

Comment: Have you tried the win-acme https://www.win-acme.com/reference/plugins/installation/iisweb

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you have configured at your provider is their http redirect service. What you probably should have configured is a dns CNAME record. The latter allows you to host your own website under your own domain with your content including setting up a https website for your own domain.

He didn’t post it as an answer. But it certainly gave me the direction to go. I didn’t realize the redirect was just putting my application inside an iframe.